# Prolog permutation type_error

Tags: prolog, swi-prolog, prolog-toplevel

Ok I am trying to use the permutation function and i get a weird type error exception.

```
permutation(X,[1,2,3]).
X = [1,2,3]
```

When I type a semicolon I get the following error:

```
ERROR: Type error: 'character_code' expected, found '-1' (an integer)
ERROR: In:
ERROR:    [11] char_code(_8378,-1)
ERROR:    [10] '$in_reply'(-1,'?h') at z/somepath/swipl/boot/init.pl:779
```

Is this a problem with my installation or am I doing something wrong? I want it to give all the possible combinations

I am running swi-pl on windows.

**UPDATE**:

I found out that it is only happening when i am running it on powershell, does anybody know why?

Comment: Post your code, from this point without the code it could be anything....

Comment: Are you using SWI Prolog's `permutation` or did you write your own? SWI already has one, which is a bad idea to redefine. If you wrote your own, choose a different name (perhaps, `permute`). And as @coder says, please show your code. This question is useless without it.

Comment: @lurker no I used the default one. I am just launching prolog and running this line.